# What is the recommended way to update a LiveData variable in ViewModel from Repository in the MVVM design pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm

I am a beginner in MVVM architecture. I want to retrieve a list of items from the database and I want to keep track of the number of items that i retrieve. I am following the MVVM design pattern. The following is the first approach I thought of:

```
class SampleViewModel extends ViewModel
{
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> count = new MutableLiveData<>();

    getItems();

    public void getItems()
    {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

        /*
        * I am skipping the code to access the database and retrieving the list
        * */

        for (String item : items)
        {
            items.add(item);
            count.setValue(items.size());
        }
    }

    LiveData<Integer> GetCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Then observe the `count` data from my activity. But, then I learned that, it is recommended to do database related tasks from the Repository and according to [this](https://proandroiddev.com/our-way-to-mvvmi-and-mistakes-we-made-when-implementing-mvvm-5f5448b5ad50) doc, LiveData variable is not recommended to be passed from ViewModel to Repository. So, my question is how can I update `count` variable from Repository or in other words,  **What is the recommended way to update a LiveData variable in ViewModel from Repository**, so that it can be observed fro the activity properly?

Comment: you can use callback mechanism, here is one sample for callback mechanism implemented https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209552/why-does-my-activity-doesnt-see-an-observed-object-changesolved/57220414#57220414

Comment: Thank u very much for the reply. So, is it ok to call an interface from the viewmodel which is declared in the repository?